# Safe dynamic PHP SQL WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

What would be a safe way (eg bindParam, prepare()) to insert a dynamic where clause. This is sent to PHP via ajax. So something comes from ajax form with

```
.php?where=name&what=bob
```

or maybe

```
.php?where=type$what=clothes
```

Then in PHP after everything is set to variables eg

```
if(isset($_POST['where'])){
  $where = $_POST['where'];
}
if(isset($_POST['what'])){
  $what= $_POST['what'];
}
```

Then a function is run to retrieve data

```
function retrieveData($db, $where, $what){
  $getData = $db->prepare("SELECT name, type, stuff FROM tbl WHERE :where = :what");
  $getData->bindParam(':what',$what);
  $getData->bindParam(':where',$where);
  $getData->execute();
 ..............
}
```

When I run a query like this i always get the SQL error about

```
'WHERE name = bob"
```

So the values are passed but I guess the SQL is not valid?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `where` is a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html wrap `:where` in backticks `\``

Comment: You can only pass data as parameter, not identifiers (i. e., database, table, column names, etc.).

Comment: Yeah, it almost works, but it always tells me that my column is unknown. So I guess the overall answer is, this is not possible in a safe way..

Comment: @user3585210 It is possible. However, you should use a whitelist of allowed columns.

Comment: Actually even by doing that, I doubt it'll even work. You'd need to use something like `WHERE $variable = :what`, because I doubt you can do a double-bind for a single statement. This being, that PDO doesn't know ahead of time what you wish to pass as a value equal to something/something. A column must already exist.

Comment: Okay thanks. I used a whitelist and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think  the string should be quoted

```
...WHERE name = 'bob'....
```

so try like this

```
 $getData->bindParam(':what',$what,PDO::PARAM_STR, 15);
 $getData->bindParam(':where',$where,PDO::PARAM_STR, 15);
```

Comment: It is accepting my :what, but still not the :where. Maybe this is not possible? There is no error, just no result. There is a result when I hardcode "name" for example.